# Rotating Exoplayer

Tags: android, rotation, exoplayer

I added exoplayer to my app.
I fixed the screen orientation to portrait for whole my app.
I need exoplayer to be rotated to landscape mode.

How can I handle this issue?
I just need to rotate the exo frame and not the whole fragment or activity.

Comment: U can try this [ExoPlayerRotation in ReactExoPlayerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078850/exoplayer-rotate-in-fullscreen)

Comment: You can try this [ExoPlayer rotation in ReactExoPlayerView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078850/exoplayer-rotate-in-fullscreen)

Answer (score 6):

You can use https://github.com/rongi/rotate-layout to draw ExoPlayer contents rotated, but for that lib to work you will have to use `app:surface_type="texture_view"` in your PlayerView

Comment: To rotate you don't need a 3rd party library. You can set `android:rotation="90"` to your layout, or call `playerView.rotation = 90f` (in Kotlin). Setting `app:surface_type="texture_view"` is a must for rotation to work.

Comment: this is the best answer, wasted 3 days and finally this solution worked specially for playerview and exoplayer

Comment: Thumb up, only this solution can work on Android TV

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by simple two lines of code,

When you click any button and want to rotate to LANDSCAPE

```
((Activity) mContext).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

And when wanna rotate back to PORTRAIT

```
((Activity) mContext).setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
```

Answer (score 1):

```java
exoPlayerView.getVideoSurfaceView().setRotation(90);
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: it doesn't work with SurfaceView

Answer (score -1):

You dont need extra library to do so, simply set   `app:surface_type="texture_view"`
and then you can rotate `texture_view` in xml using `android:rotation="39"` or in code  using `mainVideoView.rotation = 39f`:

```
  <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.SimpleExoPlayerView
            android:id="@+id/mainVideoView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:nextFocusLeft="@id/resizeLeft"
            android:nextFocusRight="@id/resizeRight"
            android:nextFocusUp="@+id/mediaContainer"
            android:nextFocusDown="@+id/exo_pause"


            app:surface_type="texture_view"
            android:rotation="39"
            app:controller_layout_id="@layout/custom_playback_control" />
```

[image]